# uniquely rename each of many files using perl

Tags: arrays, perl, rename, file-rename

I have a folder containing 96 files that I want to rename. The problem is that each file name needs a unique change...not like adding a zero the front of each name or changing extensions.  It isn't practical to do a search and replace.
Here's a sample of the names I want to change:

```
newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07A_CP.9_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07B_CP.10_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07C_CP.11_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07D_CP.12_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07E_R.1_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07F_R.3_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07G_R.4_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07H_R.5_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
```

I'd like to use perl to change the above names to the below names, respectively:

```
SEACODI_07A_A.2_sww2320H_2403F.fsa
SEACODI_07B_A.4_sww2320H_2403F.fsa
SEACODI_07C_H.1_sww2320H_2403F.fsa
SEACODI_07D_H.3_sww2320H_2403F.fsa
SEACODI_07E_H.6_sww2320H_2403F.fsa
SEACODI_07F_H.7_sww2320H_2403F.fsa
SEACODI_07G_Rb.4_sww2320H_2403F.fsa
SEACODI_07H_Rb.9_sww2320H_2403F.fsa
```

Can such a thing be done?  I have a vague idea that I might make a text file with a list of the new names and call that list @newnames.  I would make another array out of the current file names, and call it @oldnames.  I'd then do some kind of `for` loop where each element $i in @oldnames is replaced by the corresponding $i in @newnames.

I don't know how to make an array out of my current file names, though, and so I'm not sure if this vague idea is on the right track.  I keep my files with the messed-up names in a directory called 'oldnames'. The below is my attempt to make an array out of the file names in that directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; use warnings;

my $dir = 'oldnames';
opendir ('oldnames', $dir) or die "cannot open dir $dir: $!";
my @file = readdir 'oldnames';
closedir 'oldnames';

print "@file\n";
```

The above didn't seem to do anything. I'm lost. Help?

Comment: Split the problem up into 3 pieces: (1) parse the existing file names to extract the components; (2) devise a transformation that will convert the old filenames to the desired new format, and populate a map with the conversions; (3) write code to do the renames.  If you can't come up with an algorithmic transformation then your only option is a parameter file giving the old and new filenames, which you create by hand.

Comment: For how to use readdir, look at [the manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)

Comment: Speaking of strategies, I would suggest having your program output a script with one line per file, as in `mv oldname newname` and then you can run that when it looks right.

Comment: Bill: I'd rather not do a `mv` for each file, as there are about a hundred of them in total.

Comment: Jim: Unfortunately, there is no algorithm I can use. I have a spreadsheet with both the old and the new file names side by side.  Is this what you mean by a parameter file?   Also: could you explain what is meant by "populate a map with the conversions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use autodie;
use File::Copy;

# capture script name, in case we are running the script from the 
# same directory we working on. 
my $this_file = (split(/\//, $0))[-1];
print "skipping file: $this_file\n";

my $oldnames = "/some/path/to/oldnames";
my $newnames = "/some/path/to/newnames";

# open the directory
opendir(my $dh, $oldnames); 

# grep out all directories and possibly this script. 
my @files_to_rename = grep { !-d && $_ ne $this_file } readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;

### UPDATED ###
# create hash of file names from lists:
my @old_filenames = qw(file1 file2 file3 file4);
my @new_filenames = qw(onefile twofile threefile fourfile);
my $filenames = create_hash_of_filenames(\@old_filenames, \@new_filenames);
my @missing_new_file = ();  


# change directory, so we don't have to worry about pathing
# of files to rename and move... 
chdir($oldnames);
mkdir($newnames) if !-e $newnames;


### UPDATED ###
for my $file (@files_to_rename) {
    # Check that current file exists in the hash,
    # if true, copy old file to new location with new name
    if( exists($filenames->{$file}) ) { 
        copy($file, "$newnames/$filenames->{$file}");
    } else {
        push @missing_new_file, $file;
    } 
}


if( @missing_new_file ) { 
    print "Could not map files:\n", 
        join("\n", @missing_new_file), "\n";
}

# create_hash_of_filenames: creates a hash, where
# key = oldname, value = newname
# input: two array refs 
# output: hash ref 
sub create_hash_of_filenames {
    my ($oldnames, $newnames) = @_; 
    my %filenames = (); 

    for my $i ( 0 .. (scalar(@$oldnames) - 1) ) { 
        $filenames{$$oldnames[$i]} = $$newnames[$i];
    }

    # see Dumper output below, to see data structure
    return \%filenames;
}
```

Dumper result:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'file2' => 'twofile',
  'file1' => 'onefile',
  'file4' => 'fourfile',
  'file3' => 'threefile'
};
```

Running script:

```
$ ./test.pl 
skipping file: test.pl
Could not map files:
a_file.txt
b_file.txt
c_file.txt
```

File result:

```
$ ls oldnames/
a_file.txt
b_file.txt
c_file.txt
file1
file2
file3
file4

$ ls newnames/
fourfile
onefile
threefile
twofile
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to use File::Copy!  That will come in very handy. I'm sorry I was vague about what changes needed to be made.  I need to change something different in each file name.  I can't apply the same change to all of the names.  I have a list of what each name should be, and there is no pattern to them.  It's like trying to change a list of names (Betty, Sue, Billy, Bob) to the list (Andrew, Sophie, Reginald, Abigail), so that Betty becomes Andrew, Sue becomes Sophie, and so on.

Comment: @user2585169 Updated, this handles your naming issue.

Comment: +1 for a serious solution. It even checks for the script name and doesn't copy it over! Good work.  I added a messy one-liner as an unsafe alternative :-)

Comment: Thank you, thank you!  I'd upvote you if I had the right reputation, chrsblck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little odd, but it should work.  Are you running it in the directory "oldnames" or in the directory above it?  You should be in the directory above it.  A more standard way of writing it would be like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; use warnings;

my $dir = 'oldnames';
opendir ( my $oldnames, $dir) or die "cannot open dir $dir: $!";
my @file = readdir $oldnames;
closedir $oldnames;

print "@file\n";
```

This would populate `@files` with all the files in `oldnames`, *including* '.' and '..'.  You might need to filter those out depending on how you do your renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this with [rename](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.06/rename.PL)? It does allow you to use `perl` code and expressions as arguments if I recall.

The real answer is the one by @chrsblck it does some checks and doesn't make a mess.

For comparison here is a messy one liner that may suffice.  It relies on you providing a list of equivalent new file names that will rename your list of old files in the **correct order**.  Perhaps for your situation (where you don't want to do any programmatic transformation of the files names) you could just use a shell loop (see the end of this post) reading lists of new and old names from a file. A better `perl` solution would be to put **both** of these file name lists into two columns and then that file using the `-a` switch , `@F` and  then use`File::Copy` to copy the files around.

Anyway, below are some suggestions.

First, set things up:

```
 % vim newfilenames.txt # list new names one per line corresponding to old names.
 % wc -l newfilenames.txt # the same number of new names as files in ./oldfiles/
  8 newfilenames.txt
 % ls -1 oldfiles  # 8 files rename these in order to list from newfilenames.txt
 newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07A_CP.9_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
 newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07B_CP.10_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
 newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07C_CP.11_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
 newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07D_CP.12_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
 newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07E_R.1_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
 newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07F_R.3_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
 newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07G_R.4_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
 newSEACODI-sww2320H-sww24_07H_R.5_sww2320H_sww2403F.fsa
```

With files arranged as above, copy everything over:

```
perl -MFile::Copy -E 'opendir($dh , oldfiles); @newfiles=`cat newfilenames.txt`; chomp @newfiles; @oldfiles = sort grep(/^.+\..+$/, readdir $dh); END {for $i (0..$#oldfiles){copy("oldfiles/$oldfiles[$i]", "newfiles/$newfiles[$i]"); }}'
```

Not pretty: you have to `grep` and`sort` on `@oldfiles` to get rid of `. ..` and put the array elments in order. And there's always the risk that a typo could make a mess and it would be hard to figure out.
If you put the old and new names in a couple of files you could just do this with this with a shell script:

```
for i in `cat ../oldfilenames.txt` ; do ; done; for n in `cat ../newfilenames.txt`; do cp $i $n;
```

or just `cd` into  the directory with the old files and do:

```
mkdir new
for i in * ; do ; done; for n in `cat ../newfilenames.txt`; do cp $i new/$n;
```

Good luck!

Comment: I looked at `rename`.  The problem is that I don't quite know what "rule" to use.  There isn't a pattern to the name changes that I can make an algorithm for.  What I essentially need to do is replace character strings in a numbered array with strings in corresponding positions of another array of equal length...does that make sense?

Comment: Yes - I misunderstood. Your problem may be simpler then - no need for regular expressions :)

Comment: Indeed--and yet, I know not how to do it.

Comment: @user2585169 I added some examples of a `perl` one liner and a shell loop that should accomplish your task.  You should accept @chrsblck's or my answers but YOU SHOULD up vote both of us whatever you do :-)

Comment: I'd up vote you if I could--looks like I don't have enough reputation points yet ^-^

Comment: well then, either remember for later or @chrsblck should up vote me on your behalf :-)  cheers